# Xamarin and UWP - What's the point of async file opening?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms solution, which has its persistence in a UWP project. Now, for UWP, the file reading operations are made async, which causes my program to refresh itself BEFORE the async fileread is completed. Basically I have a `public async Task<CustomTable> Load(Level level)` to read the level info into a `CustomTable`. So when I update my model with a new level info:

```
_model.NewGame();
_Size = _model.Size;
```

where `NewGame()` eventually makes a call to read the level info from a file:

```
public async void NewGame()
{
...
_table = await _fileAccess.Load(_level);
....
}
```

Now I know, I shouldn't make a void async function, but the file loading IS async, so I have to make `NewGame()` async too. But if I do that, I end up having to make even the default `protected override void OnStart()` async, which I'm pretty sure is NOT the way to go. Is there any way I can read a file NOT asynchronously? What's the point in making file operations async?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which causes my program to refresh itself BEFORE the async fileread is completed

Yes. This is perfectly normal.

You'll need to design what you want your app to look like while it's loading, *synchronously* initialize into that "loading" state, and *start* the asynchronous file read(s) in your startup.

When the file read(s) complete, then you'll need to *update* your app's view with that data.

I have a [`NotifyTask<T>` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async) that may help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Any sort of IO takes time and could be blocked by other operations.  You don't want to block your app while waiting for an IO operation to complete, therefore making file IO operations async helps.